# submit(Callable<T> task) method in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

`ThreadPoolExecutor` inherits `submit(Callable<T> task)` method.
The constructor of `ThreadPoolExecutor` accepts an instance `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`.   This blocking queue can hold `Runnable` instances only.
Javadoc for `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor says:

> The queue to use for holding tasks before they are executed. This queue will hold only the Runnable tasks submitted by the execute method.

So, my question is: How tasks submitted through `submit(Callable<T> task)` are queued?

Answer (score 1):

It's wrapped into a `Runnable` (specifically a `RunnableFuture`) using `newTaskFor(Callable)`. See the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.java#AbstractExecutorService.submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the explanation in the [queuing section of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> **Queuing**
>
> Any BlockingQueue may be used to transfer and hold submitted tasks. The use of this queue interacts with pool sizing:
>
> - If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor always prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing.
> - If corePoolSize or more threads are running, the Executor always prefers queuing a request rather than adding a new thread.
> - If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will be rejected.
>
> There are three general strategies for queuing:
>
> 1. *Direct handoffs*. A good default choice for a work queue is a SynchronousQueue that hands off tasks to threads without otherwise holding them. Here, an attempt to queue a task will fail if no threads are immediately available to run it, so a new thread will be constructed. This policy avoids lockups when handling sets of requests that might have internal dependencies. Direct handoffs generally require unbounded maximumPoolSizes to avoid rejection of new submitted tasks. This in turn admits the possibility of unbounded thread growth when commands continue to arrive on average faster than they can be processed.
> 2. *Unbounded queues*. Using an unbounded queue (for example a LinkedBlockingQueue without a predefined capacity) will cause new tasks to wait in the queue when all corePoolSize threads are busy. Thus, no more than corePoolSize threads will ever be created. (And the value of the maximumPoolSize therefore doesn't have any effect.) This may be appropriate when each task is completely independent of others, so tasks cannot affect each others execution; for example, in a web page server. While this style of queuing can be useful in smoothing out transient bursts of requests, it admits the possibility of unbounded work queue growth when commands continue to arrive on average faster than they can be processed.
> 3. *Bounded queues*. A bounded queue (for example, an ArrayBlockingQueue) helps prevent resource exhaustion when used with finite maximumPoolSizes, but can be more difficult to tune and control. Queue sizes and maximum pool sizes may be traded off for each other: Using large queues and small pools minimizes CPU usage, OS resources, and context-switching overhead, but can lead to artificially low throughput. If tasks frequently block (for example if they are I/O bound), a system may be able to schedule time for more threads than you otherwise allow. Use of small queues generally requires larger pool sizes, which keeps CPUs busier but may encounter unacceptable scheduling overhead, which also decreases throughput.

Some examples can be found in the [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class which offers methods to create several types of `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: Submit() method takes callable object, whereas blocking queue can hold runnable objects only.

Answer (score 0):

Using a bounded queue with submit(Callable) is a pain because there's no default way to make it block (that I know of), even when using a BlockingQueue.

One thing that can help is to simply catch the RejectedExecutionException from the submit, then wait and try again.  This will be suitable if your application should block on submit until capacity is available in the blocking queue.  For example, wrap:

```
 futures.add(executor.submit(callable));
```

like this:

```
boolean submitted = false;
while(!submitted) {
  try {
    futures.add(executor.submit(callable));
    submitted = true;
  } catch(RejectedExecutionException e) {
    try {                       
       Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException e2) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted", e2);
    }
  }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't need to wrap any.You can crete an ExecutorService as by Executors or also directly as new ThreadPoolExecutor .Use submit(Callable) method and ThreadPoolExceutor will wrap Callable with Runnable for you .
Just pay attention if you are usign a Rejection Handler ,remember you will got the wrapper object FutureTask  containing your Callable

```
@Override
public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor){
   FutureTask ft= (FutureTask)r;
}
```